# Expected value of a random variable so that

Tags: probability, expectation

I was just shown this website so I really have no clue how things work. Let me know if I do something wrong please. Also, please bare with me because English is not my first language and I'm really bad at Math.

Me and my friend who showed me this website are doing this online course for seniors, and have no base knowledge of most advanced math .. so please bare with me.

Here's one of my first assignment exercises :

> Consider a random variable X so that :
>   $\operatorname{E}[(X-1)^2]=10$ and $\operatorname{E}[(X-2)^2]=5$
>
> *Please solve :*
>
> 1 - The expected value of X:  $\operatorname{E}[X]$
>
> 2 - The variance of X: $\operatorname{V}[X]$

In regards to this, could you please help with some tips of what subject to study (the subject, a book, a website?)

Thanks in advance,

Paulo

Comment: Hint: What is $E[(X-1)^2-(X-2)^2]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expectation is linear, so $E[(X-1)^2] = E[X^2] - 2 E[X] + 1=10$ and $E[(X-2)^2] = E[X^2 - 4 X +4] = E[X^2] - 4 E[X] +4=5$.

From these two equations, you can solve for $E[X],E[X^2]$. Then, note $var(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$.

Comment: Hello Batman, Thanks for your answer. I went to read about expectation being linear so I could really solve that as a linear equation or in this case a system of equations. So thats where I'm confused. Theres only one variable and 2 equations with diferent results, which makes it unsolvable.. I'm pretty sure i'm looking at this the wrong way. Or maybe I'm just supposed to make it simpler so it looks like the VAR formula, but in that case why are there 2 ? Is this conditional? Does the "and" means X, given X? (which also doesn't make sense). Could you help with the basic approach? Thanks again

Comment: Let $a = E[X]$, $b=E[X^2]$. Now, solve for $a$ and $b$. In general, $E[X^2] \neq (E[X])^2$.

Comment: Thank you, that was awesome. It's been many years and I am sure rusty but you've made it simple and made me look further into several subjects (like properties of expected values and approaching these)